# HTACCESS query string / character limit

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to create htaccess redirect rule for **large number of query strings** (over 900). I made this work so far;

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(string1|string2|string3)(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Since I have over 900 (string1,2,3...), I am trying to figure out more efficient way of doing this.
Is this the only way?

And/or: **How many strings can I use on one line?**

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to do? To check if any one of 900 strings (of no discernible pattern) are contained anywhere in the query string (including partial matches) on any URL-path and if so redirect to the homepage  and remove the query string?

Comment: “How many strings can I use on one line?” - That is really just an academic question, as you can always split this up into multiple conditions, which you should do anyway if only for readability. But the question that begs is whether you should be doing this in .htaccess to begin with?

Comment: Why don't you use a routing script instead? That allows to keep those strings in a database which eases development and maintenance.

Comment: Is there no other pattern to these URLs? Are these strings contained in the value of a particular URL parameter perhaps?

Comment: Thank all... 
For starters, I just dont know how else to do it.
These params are all over the place and there is no pattern that I could see (multiple subfolders, multiple php files etc....)
- routing script: I can create a php function to do this but I just dont know how to execute this for all requests, site uses php files and HTML files and PDFs (thats why htaccess seems logical)
- So does anyone know how many I can use? (string1|string2|string3|.....)

Comment: But where exactly in the query string can these _strings_ appear? Literally anywhere (including partial matches) as your regex suggests, eg. `?param=foostring1234` (matches `string1`) or only in param values or param names and should it match only whole param values or partial param values etc. Currently, your regex looks far too general.

Comment: URLs are like;
https://example.com/index.php?relationship/hearaabc961666.htm
https://example.com/hotels.php?pepper/piebfdd926253.htm
https://example.com/tours.php?exhibitor/theodfab794157.htm
https://example.com/sitemap.php?porter/literallyaffe547872.htm
https://example.com/book.php?camper/firefightersfddd316529.htm
.....
So my aim is to use the parameters (relationship|pepper|exhibitor|porter|camper......)

Comment: _"So my aim is to use the parameters"_ - "use" them, how? Why are you saying there is no discernible pattern? So far, it looks like you want whatever the query string portion of the URL starts with, up to the first slash? Are there other URLs matching that same pattern, which you _don't_ want to affect?

Comment: Yes, there aren URLs that I dont want to affect!
That is why I want to "use" the parameters to redirect (in my own words).
This site contains over 20k URLs, and 90% of the URLs are with similar structure. However, I have around 900 (parameters) that I need to redirect.
Can anyone help me?